# Keycloak Truststore for ldaps with hostname-verification-policy = ANY still fails "No subject alternative names" matching

Tags: ssl, jboss, ldap, keycloak, keycloak-services

I have create a truststore.jks containing my CA certificate and
added the SPI to standalone-ha.xml as follows:

[image]

The keystore is loaded correctly and I can check it is working if I
try to use one single LDAP server pointing by its DNS name.
But if I try to use the IP on the connection url instead of DNS, the
test authentication will always fails. ( Although test connection
works )

Connection URL: `ldaps://dc01.mydomain.com`  - WORKS

Connection URL: `ldaps://172.20.0.1`  - It fails

In the logs I can see:

[image]

I was expecting that the property `hostname-verification-policy = ANY`
would make this work.

I can not use the DNS because I intend to have a load balancer that
will ssl passthrough to the several domain controllers.

btw, I tried to use connection URL  with multiple domain controllers
like "`ldaps://dc01.mydomain.com ldaps://dc02.mydomain.com ldaps://dc03.mydomain.com`, but although this appears to work, the
moment  the dc01.mydomain.com ( first one in the list ) is offline,
keycloak stops answering, that's why I will use haproxy to
loadbalancer those connection and remove dead servers from the backend
automatically.

Any help with this ?

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem. Apparently had to do with a java update activating "Endpoint indentification" as a security improvement on LDAPS connections.

To work around this, set the java option: `-Dcom.sun.jndi.ldap.object.disableEndpointIdentification=true`

Of course this shouldn't be done in production environments.

Affected java versions, and future releases:

- 1.8.0_181-b13
- 1.7.0_191-b08
- 1.6.0_201-b07

Reference:

- Source: https://medium.com/@sajithekanayaka/solved-java-security-cert-certificateexception-no-subject-alternative-names-present-eec1669faf0d
- Release notes: https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/8u181-relnotes.html